# Запрет перетаскивания img и url браузером

Tags: html, css, javascript

Во многих браузерах (например в хроме и ие) возможно "перетащить" картинку или ссылку, зажав над ней левую кнопку мыши, допустим в адресную строку и т.д.. Требуется с помощью js запретить. Каким образом это возможно реализовать?

(написан маленький скрипт, позволяющий зажав кнопку над элементов свободно перетаскивать его. Проблема в том, что если элемент - картинка, вместо перетаскивания, браузер (хром, ие и т.д. кроме опера) захватывает его по своему, для переноса в адресную строку, на панель и прочее. Надо как-то запретить браузеру его действие по умолчанию)

p.s.

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
```

- проблемы не решают

Comment: как решить думать лень , но интересно, зачем вобще такая бредовая задача понадобилась? заказчики жестят или реально это обосновано требованиями?

Comment: Ну почему же бредовая ? Представим что у нас есть некоторая "курусель" с изображениями, и тут нам захотелось что бы мышкой можно было прокручивать изображения (перетаскивать) да и любую drag&drop задачу портит сей факт.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
el.onmousedown = function (e) {
    if (window.event.stopPropagation) window.event.stopPropagation();
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

Поидее должно помочь

Comment: К сожалению, применение данных свойств никак не помогает

Comment: unselectable="on" помогло решить проблему в IE (тестировал в 9ой версии)

Comment: В Chrome проблема была решена путём добавления следующих свойств свойств к картинке: ondrag="return false" ondragdrop="return false" ondragstart="return false"

Comment: так если ты зафиксил драг, то как теперь перетаскивание релизовывать? по onmousedown ?? =) странно что решение шурика не помогло. у меня с каруселями была беда, что при двойном клике список выделялс. но там просто даблзафиксил и все.

Answer (score 5):

Оно?

```
img { pointer-events: none; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Есть хорошее решение от WebDesignMaster-а. Надеюсь кому-то поможет)

```js
$("img, a").on("dragstart", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так, потому что некоторые картинки грузятся уже после загрузки страницы. Может быть плагины галереи или другое. Но способ работает везде.

```
    <script>
//Ставим интервал выполнения                                
    setInterval(function(){ 
//находим теги img и ставим атрибуты    
    $('img').attr({
       "ondrag":"return false",
       "ondragdrop":"return false",
       "ondragstart":"return false"
    })
//выполняем каждые 0,3 сек
}, 300);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чистый Javascript

```
var ImagesL = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (var i = 0; i < ImagesL.length; i++) {
    ImagesL[i].onmousedown = function (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

- css

  img { pointer-events: none; }

работает, вот пример

```js
// все изображения в документе
var ImagesL = document.querySelectorAll("img"); 
// перебор изображений
for (var i = 0; i < ImagesL.length; i++) {
  // для каждого изображения применяем функцию
    ImagesL[i].onmousedown = function (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
img {
  pointer-events: none; /*элемент не может стать объектом мыши*/
  user-select: none; /*запрет на перенос текста*/
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYsDP.jpg" />

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYsDP.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так:

```
mousedown = function(){//свой код drag&drop; return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [[@Getans](/users/3172/getans)](/users/3172/getans), на Internet Explorer 11 Версия 11.0.9600.16476 помогло `unselectable="on"` получилось примерно так:

```
<div class="snow_cap"><img src="images_02/snow_cap2.png" unselectable="on"/><div class="nomove"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто замените картинку на див с этой картинкой в background-image.